# Get value of deleted item in onDelete function

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui

I got a problem. I need the value of the item that got deleted with the **.onDelete** function. I am new to swift and i have no clue how to do it. It would be nice if someone could help me out here. Thanks.

The List:

```
struct TimeStampList: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var user: User
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: SingleEntriesViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<self.viewModel.timeStamps.count, id: \.self) { timeStamp in
                Section(header: Text("\(TimeStamp.convertToReadableString(date: self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].date))")) {
                    if (self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].dayType != "V") {
                        ForEach(self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].times, id: \.self) { time in
                            SingleEntriesRow(time: time, id: UUID())
                        }.onDelete { times in
                            self.deleteTimeStamps(timeStamp: timeStamp, row: times)
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Text("V")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func deleteTimeStamps(timeStamp: Int, row: IndexSet) {
        self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].deleteTime(at: row)
        self.viewModel.sortTimeStamps()
        self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].times[row] // <- I need this but row is of type IndexSet not Int.
    }
}
```

The TimeStamp:

```
struct TimeStamp: Identifiable { 
   var id = UUID() 
   var date: Date 
   var times: [String]
   var dayType: String 
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
class SingleEntriesViewModel: ObservableObject { 
   @Published var timeStamps = [TimeStamp]() 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `IndexSet` is a *collection* of indices of type `Int`.

You can either get the first index:

```
if let index = row.first {
    // index is of type `Int`
    // let result = self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].times[index]
}
```

or use a `forEach` to iterate through all indices:

```
row.forEach { index in
    // index is of type `Int`
    // let result = self.viewModel.timeStamps[timeStamp].times[index]
}
```

Comment: That's weird, I am pretty sure, that i tried row.first. It works, thank you!